# Can't get the bot to disconnect after 10 seconds

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make my discord.py bot disconnect 10 seconds after it has joined. So far I can make it join, play the audio file but not yet leave after a set amount of seconds. I have a leave function that leaves, but I want to add it to the existing function that does everything

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.voice_client import VoiceClient
import youtube_dl
import time

TOKEN = 'mytoken'

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
players = {}


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('bot online')

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def leave(ctx):
  server = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
  await server.disconnect() 


@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
  if not before.channel and after.channel and member.id == 227490621084925953:
    channel = client.get_channel(967887213939523584)
    await channel.send('KARAN IS HERE')
    voiceChannel = client.get_channel(821051726899052624)
    vc = await voiceChannel.connect() 
    vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(r"C:\Users\Amarn\OneDrive - Da Vinci College\Da Vinci College\software_developen\Assignments\jaar_1\periode_1\own_projects\discord\punjabi.mp3"), after=lambda e: print('done', e))
    time.sleep(10)   
    leave()

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: You leaked your token... regenerate it ASAP

Comment: ah thanks, I just regenerated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call the command after you've decorated it. The closest you can get is using [`invoke`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=invoke#discord.ext.commands.Context.invoke), but that requires creating context.

Instead, just inline it. You can get the guild from the member that the voice state update is about. Instead of doing `leave()`, which is invalid, you can do:

```py
await member.guild.voice_client.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `leave` function requires that it be called inside the guild (using `.leave`). What you need to do is not call `leave()` in your `on_voice_state_update`.

The [VoiceChannel#connect](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.connect) function returns a `VoiceProtocol` object. So, if you use `await vc.disconnect()` instead of `leave()` it should work fine